# SQL Server Agent job inserts fewer rows than manually package execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a simple SQL server agent job that runs a truncate table statement, then a data flow where oledb source -> lookup -> oledb destination.

When I run the package manually, all my staging table rows are inserted. However, when the package runs in my job step, about nearly 700k are missing. The staging table is the same in both cases, about 3.4M rows, so the source is identical. The destination is also identical, an empty table.

The execution information looks identical, the lookup caches the same number of rows. The only difference is that the oledb destination writes 3.4M rows on manual execution, but only 2.7M on job step execution. There are no other jobs running concurrently.

I am flabbergasted. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is too broad for us to troubleshoot, especially without your code.

Comment: It's literally truncating the destination, taking the entire contents of the staging table, and fast loading it into the destination. Does that help?

Comment: A bit yes. Is this repeatable? Does the agent service account have the same permissions?

Comment: Is the error output for the destination set to ignore?

Comment: Thanks guys - repeatable, yes, nightly the load is smaller than expected, and running manually or triggering the job step manually always yields all rows. No error output, it will just fail. SQL agent service account should have permission to just about everything

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I feel like there must be something overlapping that I'm unaware of that's perhaps locking some resource. I have no other inkling of why in isolation everything works just fine. I do appreciate the ideas very much guys.

Comment: From what I can gather, your manual execution of the package and the job happens at different times, correct? If so, could the data have changed?

Comment: Whenever I run into an issue like this that doesn't make sense, I try to think about other possible causes unrelated to my code. 

For example, can you guarantee that your package that is running under the job is definitely the same that you are running in isolation? When you compile your SSIS package, did you do a build or a rebuild? 

Other thoughts - Delete the job and create a new one from scratch; Try creating the job on a different server. Basically anything you can do to rule out causes such as permissions etc.

Comment: It's definitely a timing thing. I've tried isolating the staging table source, so I do know exactly how many rows I'm expecting. The builds are exactly the same. Even putting the step last in the job and running from that step will result in the correct row count. It MUST be something else concurrent that's locking it out. Thanks again for the input, no pun intended.